# How to get object keys without modules or libraries in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, adobe, extendscript

How would to do something like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObj);`, `Object.keys(myObj);` or `for (k in myObj)` with `"noLib": true`?

I'm getting errors like `Property 'getOwnPropertyNames' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.` or `error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Extract'.` when using `for (k in value)`.

I'm trying to build a script for Adobe Illustrator with typescript using [Types for Adobe library](https://github.com/bbb999/Types-for-Adobe) and since Adobe's extend script doesn't have all functionalities of common JS, the author of the library suggest to use `"module": "none","noLib": true` in `tsconfig.json`

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any ExtendScript project where you want to use modern JS constructs, you're going to need a large number of polyfills. (Think of it about like targeting IE8.) [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is sure to be part of that approach; there's also a [Babel preset for ExtendScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-extendscript). In this sort of arrangement, TypeScript will feed into Babel and Babel will produce the actual ExtendScript.

As for the library you're using, they recommend `"noLib": true` because their typings redeclare all the JS primitives with the limited interfaces supported in ExtendScript itself. If you'll be using Babel, you should have TypeScript target a more modern level of JS and let Babel take care of the other details. That would mean removing `"noLib"` and setting the `"target"` to something like `"ES2015"`. I'm not sure how that will interact with the primitive typings bundled into `Types-for-Adobe`; you may need to do something fancy to bypass them.

(Editorial comment: It's 2021 and the real answer should be for Adobe to bring ExtendScript up to at least 2011 standards...)

Comment: So agree with the editorial comment! I'll look into that, thank you :)